# Copy Azure Analysis Services Model to be used with a new database sources

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-sql-database, azure-analysis-services

I currently have an azure database connected to an azure analysis services model. The model already has calculated columns, calculated tables, measures, etc. that is used for easier power bi analysis. This was done in visual studio.

Soon I will need to create new databases that have the same table structure as the original, and they will also need to be added to azure analysis services for analysis.

I want to be able to copy the analysis services model with the additional calculated features to be used with the new databases. This should be okay because the new databases have the same structure and table names as the original database. So far visual studio hasn't let me delete the original data source or add the new one in order to process the data from the new database on analysis services.

I really wouldn't want to start from scratch in visual studio with each new database, and have to redo all the same dax calculations each time.

Any idea how to copy the original model for the new data sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to be able to copy the analysis services model with the additional calculated features to be used with the new databases.

Simply copy the Visual Studio project and change the Data Source to point to the correct database.

[image]